# Генерация случайного числа, одинакового в течении часа

Tags: javascript, python, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Есть масса различных элементов и два возможных состояния у каждого. Нужно, чтобы это состояние рандомно генерировалось и не менялось в течении часа. Состояние каждого элемента не должно храниться в системе, а должно генерироваться по необходимости. Как это сделать? Пока есть идея такая - на основе номера часа и номера дня (чтобы каждый день новое и не повторялось в одинаковые часы каждого дня) и названия элемента сгенерировать случайное число от 1 до 10, если меньше 5 - то первое состояние, если больше - то второе. Но как сгенерировать число на основе другого числа? Или как ещё можно генерировать неизменное состояние (одно из двух), так, чтобы оно было одинаковым весь час? Нужно, чтобы это работало либо на сервере (Python, Django), либо на клиенте (JavaScript, Angular).

Приведу пример. Есть элементы **А, В, С**. И два состояния - **1** и **2**. Допустим, в 20:00 часов при запросе их состояние вернётся **А-1, В-1, С-2**. Если сделать запросы в 20:05, 20:22, 20:45 и так далее, что вернётся всё равно **А-1, В-1, С-2**. Но если сделать запрос в следующий час, например в 21:03, то вернутся другие состояния для элементов, например **А-2, В-1, С-1**. Они не должны храниться где то, а должны именно генерироваться. Как такое сделать?

Comment: Число генерить на сервере раз в час по cron, а у клиента хранить в виде куки.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics число не должно нигде храниться, а генерироваться на лету.

Comment: `Состояние каждого элемента не должно храниться в системе` вот в этот момент у Вас начались выдуманные проблемы из ничего. 1. Храните случайное число на сервере. 2 если оно устарело, то обновляете его штатными средствами генерации ПСЧ

Comment: Если бы данные можно было генерить из ничего, то по теории Шеннона был бы незачёт у профессора, а не у студента.

Comment: Я же объяснил. На основе имени элемента и номера текущего дня в месяце. Проще говоря - передаёшь строку функции, а она создаёт из неё число. Как это реализовать?

Comment: 0 часов - число 0, 1 час - число 1, ... 23 часа - число 23

Comment: Ну посчитайте что-то типа CRC32 от строки `YYYYMMDDhh` - будут к тому же достаточно различные числа... Или вам нужна какая-то криптостойкость, чтоб враг повторить не смог? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `seed` из модуля `range`. Меняете seed раз в час и у вас будут новые значения. `seed` можно устанавливать исходя из чего угодно, даты, времени, числа или строки.

Например:

```
 import random

 random.seed(12345)
 for _ in range(5):
     print("%.3f" % random.random())

 print()

 random.seed(12345)
 for _ in range(5):
    print("%.3f" % random.random())

 #меняем seed и получаем новую последовательность
 print()

 random.seed(54321)
 for _ in range(5):
     print("%.3f" % random.random())
```

Answer (score 2):

Решил использованием встроенной функции `hash`. Я передаю ей название элемента и текущую дату, получая в ответ числовой хэш, различающийся при разной дате и одинаковый при одинаковых параметрах.

Comment: Я не уверен, что встроенная функция `hash` достаточно хорошо "разбрасывает" значения. Например `''.join([str(hash(str(i) + 'a') % 2) for i in xrange(24)])` дает нам строку `'101010101010101010100101'`.